# How to insert xml data into the Node and get the relationship in Tree

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to write a xml parser, very simple and I need to know how to use these class in the main class to do Tree from a xml file without use DOM or SAX.
I don´t understand how insert child nodes using recursivity, mine two class are:

```
public class XmlNode {

    private final String strTag;
    private final List<Node> children;

    public Node(String strTag) {
        this.strTag= strTag;
        this.children = new ArrayList<Node>();
    }

    public String getTagName() {
        return strTag;
    }

    public void addChild(XmlNode child) {
        children.add(child);
    }
}


public class XmlTree {

    private XmlNode root; 

    public XmlTree() {
        this.root = null;
    }

    public XmlTree(XmlNode root) {
        this.root = root;        
    }

    public XmlNode getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public void setRoot(XmlNode root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    public int size() {
        int numberOfNodes = 0;

        if(root != null) {
            numberOfNodes = size(root) + 1; //1 para la raiz
        }
        return numberOfNodes;
    }

    private int size(XmlNode node) {
        int numberOfNodes = node.getNumberOfChildren();

        for(XmlNode child : node.getChildrenNode()) {
            numberOfNodes += size(child);
        }

        return numberOfNodes;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't get your point. Are you trying to write your own parser?

Comment: Is it a requirement that you use recursion to build your tree? If I were being tasked with creating a Tree structure out of `Nodes` from an xml representation I would keep a `Stack<Node>`, while I parsed as I hit the opening of a tag I would put a `Node` for it on the stack, and when I hit the closing tag I would pop it off, adding children to the current node and putting them on the stack as needed.

Comment: Hi Hoons could you show me a litle sample that how implement using Stack<Node>.